# Autodesk java api response mapping

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are using the forge-api-java-client. There is an issue in Model Derivatives getManifest call.

The response fails mapping with a single Message String being returned instead of the expected String Array.

Have switched to using local build of the jar, change in file Message.java to include an alternative constructor for the class setMessage

```
  public void setMessage(String message) {
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    messages.add(message);
    setMessage(messages);
  }
```

Could this change be merged into the project.

Answer (score 0):

We'll check it, but as of today, that package is just under maintenance. You are welcome to submit a [PR](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client/pulls).